# PHP error logging with Syslog-NG

Tags: php, syslog-ng

I've got some logs gathered on a monitoring server using Syslog-NG which are :

- copied into a local daily-rotated file,
- stored into a MySQL database.

Unfortunately, no error is raised since they are evaluated as PHP notices ([see this post](http://www.janoszen.com/2012/04/26/logging-php-errors-to-syslog-ng/)).

Hence, I am wondering what's the right way to use Syslog-NG to handle PHP errors so that they are actually recognized as errors.

Comment: Have you looked at [syslog](http://php.net/manual/en/function.syslog.php) ?

Answer (score 0):

Several things/options here.  That article doesn't mention configuring *php.ini* to use syslog for error logging inside of php.  You'll need to set

```
error_log = syslog
```

I'm assuming that was alluded to in the article where it says

> PHP has a annoying habit of logging everything with the NOTICE error
>   level.

You could turn on error logging to syslog that way and follow the syslog voodoo suggested in that article, or you could do it *the PHP way*, and by that I mean using more of PHP to implement the mapping between PHP errors & syslog error levels.

Define a custom error handler via [set_error_handler](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php), then within the handler, map a particular PHP error to some particular syslog error level eg

```
function myErrorHandler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline)
{
    if (!(error_reporting() & $errno)) {
        // This error code is not included in error_reporting
        return;
    }

    switch ($errno) {
    case E_USER_ERROR:
        $str = "<b>My ERROR</b> [$errno] $errstr<br />\n" .
               "  Fatal error on line $errline in file $errfile" .
               ", PHP " . PHP_VERSION . " (" . PHP_OS . ")<br />\n" .
               "Aborting...<br />\n";
        syslog(LOG_CRIT, $errstr)
        exit(1);
        break;
    case E_USER_WARNING:
        // ...
}
```

It might also be a neat idea to do the same with [set_exception_handler](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-exception-handler.php).

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed this post via my referral logs on my blog you linked. The problem with syslog is that **you don't have any guarantee that your message will actually arrive** to the log store. Granted, PHP could be patched to give you an error message, but if you need transactioned logs, you are a lot better off storing them into the database directly.

If you insist on doing it this way, [here's a library](https://github.com/szeber/yapep_base/blob/master/src/YapepBase/Syslog/NativeSyslogConnection.php) I've helped develop that will replace the native syslog interface of PHP. It's written entirely in PHP so you don't need to compile anything.

I hope this helps.